# Parental control but not restriction

Tags: parental-controls

I would like to have a way to measure the spent time in the computer in each application.

In the case of my son, he has an account in the desk computer, he use it for play a game and also to watch cartoons on netflix/youtube. I would like to measure how much time he spends on each thing, I do not want to restrict the internet as parent control usually does, just know how much time my son spend if he does not have restrictions.

If there is a way to do it I would like to implement it in my own account as well with more than 2 applications.

By the way, I am using sparky linux, hope this is not a big problem... thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately your distribution is no (official) flavour of Ubuntu and off topic here. You can ask questions about any Linux distribution over on [Unix.SE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [WhatPulse](http://whatpulse.org/). In theory if you set this program to autostart in your child’s account it will track how much time he spent on specific applications, and also some other things. However, I think your son may simply turn it off if he opens it himself and chooses quit.

If anyone knows of a more elegant solution, please share.